# Expectation of this integral $\mathbb{E}\left[\min\{X,a\} \int_X^\infty \min\{t^{-2},b\} ~dt\right] $

Tags: probability, integration, expectation

Let $X$ be a positive random variable with CDF $F_X(x)$, and $a$ and $b$ are two positive constant (we don't know the relation between $a$ and $b$), how should I start to evaluate the following:
$$
\mathbb{E}\left[\min\{X,a\} \int_X^\infty \min\{t^{-2},b\} ~dt\right].
$$
**I am able to obtain** $\mathbb{E}\left[\min\{X,a\}\right]$ **and** $\mathbb{E}\left[\int_X^\infty \min\{t^{-2},b\} ~dt\right]$.

Any hints?

Comment: $ \min\{t^{-2},b\}$ or $ \min\{t,b\}$?

Comment: One can somewhat simplify this, using $$\int_X^\infty \min\{t^{-2},c^{-2}\}dt=\int_X^\infty (c^{-2}\mathbf 1_{t<c}+t^{-2}\mathbf 1_{t>c})dt=\frac{c-\min\{X,c\}}{c^2}+\frac1{\max\{X,c\}}$$ but after that, except if $c=a$, that is, $a^2b=1$...

Answer (score 0):

$$\int_X^\infty \min(t,b)dt = \mathbb 1 [1/X^2\leq b]\int_X^\infty 1/t^2 dt + \mathbb 1 [1/X^2> b]\left[ (\frac 1 {\sqrt b} -X)\frac 1 {b^2} + \int_b^\infty 1/t^2 dt \right]\\
= \mathbb 1 [X\geq \frac 1 {\sqrt b}]\frac 1 X + \mathbb 1 [X<\frac 1 {\sqrt b}]\left[ (\frac 1 {\sqrt b} -X)\frac 1 {b^2} + \frac 1 b\right]
$$
The 1/X term doesn't smell good, some relation between $a$ and $b$ would kill it.